# How to programatically track the network usage of a process in windows using python?

Tags: python, windows, networking

I want to be able to read the data shown in the image [image: Process monitor showing the network usage data for process]

I want to be record the total sent bytes and received bytes for a particular process  and address over a period of time.

Comment: There are two questions here: 1) does Windows provide the values you're looking for (network I/O bytes on a per-process basis)?  2) Can you read those values from Windows using Python?  You might look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WmiSdk/wmi-classes) for the former question, and [here](https://blog.ipswitch.com/managing-windows-system-administration-with-wmi-and-python) for the latter.